# Is there a way to find the absolute path of a file within a project without it changing the current working directory?

Tags: python, file, parsing, directory, directory-structure

My code to get the file actually works.

```
def get_file(self):
    file_path = Path('file-folder/testfile.txt').absolute()
    with file_path.open(mode='r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        return commentjson.loads(data)
```

It is when I am testing the code I run into an issue. I get an assertion error saying the file does not exist when it is clearly in the file structure when the real code runs.

```
o = MyObject()
f = o.get_file()
self.assertIsNotNone(f)
```

the new value for the file_path is `driveletter/directoryofproject/project/currentyworkingdirectory/tests/file-folder/testfile.txt` and it does not exist in this directory only in the `driveletter/directoryofproject/project/currentworkingdirectory/file-folder/testfile.txt` directory

Comment: When you're testing, does `file-folder/` exist in the current working dir?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes but the `new` value for the `file_path` is `currentyworkingdirectory/tests/file-folder/testfile.txt` and it does not exist in this directory only in the `currentworkingdirectory/file-folder/testfile.txt directory`

Comment: So you want to use either `project/file-folder` or `tests/project/file-folder`, depending if you're in a production or test environment?

Comment: `Path('file-folder/testfile.txt').absolute()` will use the current working directory when determining the absolute path — so the code is dependent upon what that is when it's executed.